# Vuex4 - Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'state')

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, vuejs3

I'm using `Vue3` and `Vuex4`, I keep getting the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'state')
    at ReactiveEffect.eval [as fn] (App.vue?3dfd:36)
    at ReactiveEffect.run (reactivity.esm-bundler.js?a1e9:160)
    at ComputedRefImpl.get value [as value] (reactivity.esm-bundler.js?a1e9:1087)
    at setup (App.vue?3dfd:37)
    at callWithErrorHandling (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:6656)
    at setupStatefulComponent (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:6272)
    at setupComponent (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:6228)
    at mountComponent (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:4081)
    at processComponent (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:4056)
    at patch (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:3651)
```

I'm trying to set the "hello" to the message variable so I can use it throughout my app, This is my `main.js` file:

```
import { createApp} from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'
import { createStore } from 'vuex';


const store = createStore({
  state(){
    return{
      message: 'hello'
    }
  }
})


createApp(App).use(router, store).mount('#app')
```

This is my App.vue file, I'm trying to receive it with the composition api using the computed function.

```
import { ref, computed } from 'vue'
import { useStore } from 'vuex'

export default {
  name: 'App',
  setup(){
    const store = useStore();

    const message = computed(() => store.state.message);
    console.log(message.value);

    return{ }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try with:

```
createApp(App)
  .use(router)
  .use(store)
  .mount('#app')
```